# How big is Lord Dominator's ship?

Tags: spaceship, wander-over-yonder

In the show, *Wander Over Yonder*, season two, we see the main villain, Lord Dominator. She has a Star Destroyer-like ship that looks kind of like it is made of lava, and it is shown as being larger than several planets. How big is this ship?

Comment: According to the wiki, which doesn't provide any citations or anything for this information, it's "massive but smaller than a star destroyer".

Comment: well, that wiki is helpful